# How to lookup/match rows and columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need help.

How to lookup or match rows and columns? From my Master File rows I have Customer Code and from columns I have BARCODE. I want to match them based on Customer Code and BARCODE(highlights in yellow).

Master File:
[image]

Raw File:
[image]

Sample Output:
[image]

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a simple example to follow in order to achieve you goal.

**Example:**

Looking for number **2** and letter **C**. The answer is **NHTY**, where letter and number meet.

**To get:**

- **Column Number:** `=MATCH(F2,$A$1:$D$1,0)`
- **Row Number:** `=MATCH(F3,$A$1:$A$5,0)`
- **Result:** `=INDEX($A$1:$D$5,MATCH(F3,$A$1:$A$5,0),MATCH(F2,$A$1:$D$1,0))`

**Tips:**

- In Column & Row calculation use fix ranges.
- Use fix range for `INDEX()`

**Image:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have the answer in you title, you simply need to index the raw file and then match rows and columns

```
=INDEX(RawFile!$A$1:$C$12,MATCH(MasterFile!$A2,RawFile!$A$1:$A$12,0),MATCH(MasterFile!C$1,RawFile!$A$1:$C$1,0))
```

Adapt the ranges/references to your needs

[INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)
[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

Comment: Thanks sir for your help!